# How can I pass a text file created by php to my python script for processing?

Tags: php, python

I have a php code that is writing the user input on the webpage into a text file. I wish to pass the text file into my python script that looks like follows:

## PHP Script (getfile.php)

```
<?php

function writetofile($file, $content, $writeType){
    $fo = fopen($file, $writeType);
    if($fo){
        fwrite($fo,$content);
        fclose($fo);
    }   
}
?>
```

## Python Script (predict.py)

```
clf=joblib.load('model.pkl')

def run(command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    return output

row = run('cat '+'/Users/minks/Documents/X-test.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
print("Test row size:")
print(row)
matrix_tmp_test = np.zeros((int(row),col), dtype=np.int64)
print("Test matrix size:")
print(matrix_tmp_test.size)
```

What I am asking is, after writing to a file : `$file` in php, how can I then pass this file to replace:

```
 row = run('cat '+'/Users/minks/Documents/X-test.txt'+" | wc -l").split()[0]
```

where the path gets replace by `$file` and the processing continues? Also, is it possible to pass `$file` directly to the python code via command line? I am little confused on how this entire passing and processing can be carried out.

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` in python and sun a system exec command on your script and pass the file path as an argument.

Comment: @Torxed: But how do l ensure that the file automatically goes and fits inside that particular 'row' statement? There are other file calls inside the python code as well

Answer (score 1):

Dow you want something like this?

PHP:

```
$path = "my.txt";
system("python predict.py $path");
```

Python:

```
row = run("cat %s | wc -l" % sys.argv[1]).split()[0]
```